# Access from map, casting string to char*

Tags: c++, dictionary, casting

I have the following problem with casting (or accessing data, I'm not sure):

There is `map<int, string> keys` I use to describe buttons, number matches the Allegro5 key code (eg. `keys[81] = "PgDown"`). I want to print data on the screen using al_draw_text, which needs `char*` parameter to be passed.

I tried access data this way:

```
char dropdownBuffer[16];
cout << keys[dropdownKeyCode] << endl;
sprintf_s(dropdownBuffer, "%s", keys[dropdownKeyCode]);
cout << dropdownBuffer << endl;
gui.drawButton(CLIENT_PADDING, CLIENT_PADDING+50+219, 123, 38, dropdownBuffer);
```

Console should print string `Spacja` twice, but second time there are some random chars.

What am I doing wrong now? Maybe there is other possible way to cast this string to char?

Comment: Use `c_str()` to get a `const char *`. Pretending a `std::string` is a `char *` is a bad idea.

Comment: It gives me another error: error C2664: 'GUI::drawButton' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'const char *' to 'char *'.

Comment: Then copy it. `sprintf` should be fine with that.

Comment: *Never, ever, ever* pass a C++ object through `...`! Not even once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get pointer to data from string, use c_str(), see ref: [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

replace code:

```
sprintf_s(dropdownBuffer, "%s", keys[dropdownKeyCode]);
```

with:

```
sprintf_s(dropdownBuffer, "%s", keys[dropdownKeyCode].c_str());
```

Comment: That's not right. `c_str()` returns `const char*` not `char *`

Comment: @Rapptz, he makes a copy from string, const char* should be fine?

Comment: @billz, I think Rapptz means your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I thought sprintf_s needs a sizeof argument.

```
sprintf_s(dropdownBuffer, sizeof(dropdownBuffer), "%s", keys[dropdownKeyCode]);
```

or

```
const char* dropdownBuffer = keys[dropdownKeyCode].c_str();
```